# Delegate error converting from VB6 to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6, delegates

Trying to adapt a card reader from VB6 to vb.net. I'm getting this error after converting:

```
'AddressOf' expression cannot be converted to 'Integer' because 'Integer' is not a delegate type
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
Public Sub SetupCallBacks()
    'UPGRADE_WARNING: Add a delegate for AddressOf OnEventDeviceStateChanged Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="E9E157F7-EF0C-4016-87B7-7D7FBBC6EE08"'
    Call MTUSCRADeviceStateChangedNotify(AddressOf OnEventDeviceStateChanged)
    'UPGRADE_WARNING: Add a delegate for AddressOf OnEventCardDataStateChanged Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="E9E157F7-EF0C-4016-87B7-7D7FBBC6EE08"'
    Call MTUSCRACardDataStateChangedNotify(AddressOf OnEventCardDataStateChanged)
End Sub


Public Sub OnEventDeviceStateChanged(ByVal parm As Integer)
    If (gbEvents) Then
        If (glDeviceState <> parm) Then
            glDeviceState = parm
        End If

        Select Case glDeviceState
            Case MTSCRA_STATE_DISCONNECTED
                SetStatus(("OnEventDeviceStateChanged:Disconnected"))
            Case MTSCRA_STATE_CONNECTED
                SetStatus(("OnEventDeviceStateChanged:Connected"))
            Case MTSCRA_STATE_ERROR
                SetStatus(("OnEventDeviceStateChanged:Error"))
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

As far as I know I need to do something with delegates, but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a delegate, like this:

```
Delegate Sub DeviceStateChangedDelegate(ByVal param As Integer)
```

Then inside of the `SetupCallBacks` method you need to create and invoke your delegate, like this:

```
Public Sub SetupCallBacks()
    ' Declare and instantiate the delegate
    Dim MTUSCRADeviceStateChangedNotify As DeviceStateChangedDelegate
    MTUSCRADeviceStateChangedNotify = AddressOf OnEventDeviceStateChanged

    ' Invoke the delegate, passing it 10, which is obviously made up
    MTUSCRADeviceStateChangedNotify.Invoke(10)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and this did fix that issue, but my lowly intern mind failed to realize that using this method for reading the HID requires a .dll file that won't be used in the function it is going to belong to...

Comment: @user2620509 Is `MTUSCRACardDataStateChangedNotify` in an external DLL? I.e. is it defined by a `Declare` statement? In which case I don't think this answer applies.